# Simplify Polygon - Clipper Library Angus Johnson

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon, clipping

I'm trying to simplify a complex polygon drawn on Google maps (API v3 Javascript). My goal is to receive an array of simple polygons. The problem is that some of the figures I draw could be analyzed and some of them could not.

For example:

1) Figure 8-vertical - For polygon (var areaPolygon) with coordinates:

```
{42.15093256154524, 24.746017456054687}
{42.149087174176515, 24.740352630615234}
{42.14049586965896, 24.754257202148437}
{42.1333673840616, 24.747648239135742}
{42.13795007405907, 24.73846435546875}
{42.145841707270215, 24.74867820739746}
{42.15093256154524, 24.749107360839843}
{42.15093256154524, 24.746017456054687}
```

it's working fine - the SimplifyPolygon returns 2 simple polygons

2) Figure 8-horizontal -  For polygon (var areaPolygon) with coordinates:

```
{42.145523515284395, 24.744129180908203}
{42.15016895950386, 24.749279022216797}
{42.14603262169405, 24.7646427154541}
{42.14978715502878, 24.769277572631836}
{42.15055076167604, 24.758892059326172}
{42.14393253136682, 24.75193977355957}
{42.141705086714666, 24.747648239135742}
{42.14348704870535, 24.74472999572754}
{42.145523515284395, 24.744129180908203}
```

- it's not working - the SimplifyPolygon returns the same complex polygon

Here is my code:

```
function analyzePolygon(areaPolygon) {

//areaPolygon is google.maps.Polygon
var subj_polygon = new ClipperLib.Polygon();
var result_polygons = new ClipperLib.Polygons();

//LatLng coordinates to integer coordinates
for(var i = 0; i < areaPolygon.getPath().getArray().length ; i++) {
    subj_polygon.push(new ClipperLib.IntPoint(Math.round(areaPolygon.getPath().getArray()[i].lat()*100000000000000), Math.round(areaPolygon.getPath().getArray()[i].lng()*100000000000000)));
}

var cpr = new ClipperLib.Clipper();

result_polygons = cpr.SimplifyPolygon(subj_polygon, ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftNonZero);

//for each simple polygon - make a request and populate markers of the objects which are in these bounds
for(var j=0; j < result_polygons.length; j++) {

    var rpStringify = JSON.stringify(eval(result_polygons[j]));
    var rpJSON = JSON.parse(rpStringify);
    var arrayPolygon = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rpJSON.length; i++) {

        var tempObject = JSON.stringify(eval(rpJSON[i]));
        var objectJSON = JSON.parse(tempObject);
        var tempArr = [2];
        tempArr[0] = objectJSON.X/100000000000000;
        tempArr[1] = objectJSON.Y/100000000000000;
        arrayPolygon[i]= tempArr; 
    }

    loadPinsPolygon(arrayPolygon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elena.

> it's not working - the SimplifyPolygon returns the same complex polygon

I'm not sure what you mean by a 'complex polygon', but if you mean a self-intersecting polygon (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_polygon), then the SimplifyPolygon function does indeed remove the self-intersection as expected. What you are getting is a single simple polygon, though with 2 vertices at the same coordinates at the prior point of intersection.

[image: simple polygon]

However, if you really want two discrete polygons then you'll have to modify the underlying code in the library (see discussion [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/discussion/1148419/thread/4e614a38/).)

Answer (score 0):

Clipper version 6 can produce truly simple polygons also in cases where point is on the polygon line segment (not crossing the segment, but touching it), if `StrictlySimple` is set to true. I'm not tested this yet, but I refer to the Angus Johnson's comment here:
https://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/discussion/1148419/thread/813a62c8/

Below is an example of such polygon. The fifth point is touching the vertical line segment. The result of simplifying in this case is two triangles.

[image]

The javascript version of Clipper 6 is not coming immediately after release, but within some delay.